# React Native App with Wordpress API

Tags: wordpress, react-native

I'm planning to develop mobile app showing the contents of Wordpress posts with WP api.

I'll use React Native (, actually I can use only RN for developing mobile app ), but I'm not sure how to display contents of posts with the same line-breaks and styles as they are on the Wordpress site.

Please tell me how to deal with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to bring your html content into something like React Native HTML View: https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview

That will probably work for the basics displaying html content in React Native.

In terms of styles and getting things to look the same in React Native as it does in Wordpress, you may have to create your styles in react native and process your content from the WP API instead.  It is probably going to be a combination of both.  For instance I've made a WP app where I'm using HTML View for the content portion of posts but using  and  in React Native for other parts of the content like the title, author and so on.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm sorry for being late to reply.
Thank you for your answer, that will help me, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress use wpautop() function to adds those line-breakes.
You need JS analog of this function. Check here https://www.npmjs.com/package/wpautop